# Can I use SharePoint Designer 2013 to edit SharePoint 2010 sites?

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, 2013

Can I use SharePoint Designer 2013 to edit SharePoint 2010 sites?

Couldn't find this info in the web.

Comment: my First thought is why you need spd 2013 for 2010. why dont use SPD 2010? its clearly written on MSDN that it will not support earlier versions.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Doesn't seem so.  I just tried and got the following message

> Microsoft SharePoint Designer cannot be used to edit web sites on
>   servers different from Microsoft SharePoint Server 2013.  To edit
>   these sites, you need to use the same version of SharePoint Designer
>   which matches the version of Microsoft SharePoint Server.

Comment: You need Designer 2007 for SP 2007, Designer 2010 for SP 2010, and Designer 2013 for SP 2013.  No way around it.

Comment: That's what I thought, but didn't have 2013 to test. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can edit SP13 in SPD10!
http://365.webbrewers.com/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=25

Comment: Margo, the question is the other way around.
Can SPD 2013 be used to edit SP 2010 sites NOT can SPD 2010 be used to edit SP 2013 sites.

Answer (score 0):

When SharePoint Designer 2013 was new, I know for a fact that I used it to connect to SharePoint Server 2010. But it may have been updated, because it's giving the above error now. Too bad, too. 2013 allows copying and pasting of custom workflow content!